# Hive not launching mapreduce jobs.. getting stuck in the middle of execution

Tags: hive, hadoop2

I am trying to select count(*) from a table but, after submitting the job, it is getting stuck. PFB the details.

```
hive> select count(*) from txnrecords;
WARNING: Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.
Query ID = sambit_20161108115544_170f01cb-5825-4af1-8607-d25ceb84823b
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Starting Job = job_1478581699153_0005, Tracking URL = http://localhost:8088/proxy/application_1478581699153_0005/
Kill Command = /home/sambit/hadoop-2.7.3/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1478581699153_0005
```

**Note:** (select * from txnrecords;) is working fine as below.

```
hive> select * from txnrecords;
OK
0   06-26-2011  4007024 40.33   Exercise & Fitness  Cardio Machine Accessories  Clarksville Tennessee   credit
1   06-26-2011  4006742 198.44  Exercise & Fitness  Weightlifting Gloves    Long Beach  California  credit
2   06-26-2011  4009775 5.58    Exercise & Fitness  Weightlifting Machine Accessories   Anaheim California  credit
3   06-26-2011  4002199 198.19  Gymnastics  Gymnastics Rings    Milwaukee   Wisconsin   credit
4   12-17-2011  4002613 98.81   Team Sports Field Hockey    Nashville   Tennessee   credit
5   12-17-2011  4007591 193.63  Outdoor Recreation  Camping & Backpacking & Hiking  Chicago Illinois    credit
6   12-17-2011  4002190 27.89   Puzzles Jigsaw Puzzles  Charleston  South Carolina  credit
7   12-17-2011  4002964 96.01   Outdoor Play Equipment  Sandboxes   Columbus    Ohio    credit
8   12-18-2011  4007361 10.44   Winter Sports   Snowmobiling    Des Moines  Iowa    credit
9   12-18-2011  4004798 152.46  Jumping Bungee Jumping  St. Petersburg  Florida cash
10  12-18-2011  4004646 180.28  Outdoor Recreation  Archery Reno    Nevada  cash
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Time taken: 0.227 seconds, Fetched: 12 row(s)
```

[Queue Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wnv62.png)

Comment: This could be yarn configuration issue. There isn't enough resource to run this job.

Comment: visit  Tracking URL = http://localhost:8088/proxy/application_1478581699153_0005/ ,  check the job is in the right JOB_QUEUE.

Comment: @SathiyanS.. could you please tell me how to set that. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeGan.. Thanks for your help. As I am new in Hive, not sure if I am going in the wright track. The job is going into the default queue and when I selected the hyperlink it showed as per the attached snapshot ("Queue Details").
Please let me know if I am following any wrong steps.

Answer (score 0):

"select * from" works different from "select count(*)", the last one does more things. So don't count on this. 
In my experience this issue is due to the use of a reserved keyword into the table column definition, if so then into the container log there is an error message like : ParseException. The suggestion from Mike Gan is the best option you have. Execute

```
yarn logs -applicationId <yourApplicationIdFromHive>
```

to get the log of the container.

Comment: When i try to see the details of that job i get the following "Total Allocated Containers: 0".. could you please suggest me anything to resolve this.

Comment: Does   SELECT * FROM txnrecords ORDER BY <add here a field> work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do YARN tuning for it.
The user cache and file cache might be full and there is sufficient memory to execute MapReduce jobs.
You can view the current cache size using:

```
du -hs /yarn/nm/usercache/root/filecache
```

You can delete the cache file using:

```
rm -rf /yarn/nm/usercache/root/filecache
```

Mapreduce jobs will execute post deleting the cache.
[Execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkD4V.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem using group by query, after a while seeing the logs of the job in http://localhost:8088/cluster/app/<your_app_id> it displays a SocketTimeout error what I did was to run stop-all.sh and format the namenode conserving my data. After that I was able to run my query. I hope this help. I don't really know the root causes of this.